# 3D effect jquery css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, 3d

I must cake a simple 3D effect with jQuery and css3.

Actually I cook this http://www.agencevolt.fr/milestone-nicolas/ and I use perspective and `rotateY`, `rotateX` on `<div class="container">` and I use an parallax effect on `<img>`. But I can't reach an deep effect. I used a "trick" to resize width of pictures on a new version, but it's "ugly". Do you have an idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Please put the relevant code in your question for archive purposes

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove

```
overflow: hidden;
```

from the container and add on the container

```
transform-style:preserve-3d;
```

then on images play with

```
transform:translate3d(x,y,z)
```

something like

```
transform:translate3d(0,0,100px)
```

should solve it ;)